# How I can get data on server when I send it in android by multipart

Tags: android, multipartentity

I have trouble with received data on server. I have android app which send data by multipartentity. I want to send two files (video and image).
This is code from android:

```
protected void uploadStuff(String videoPath, String backgroundPath, String Url) throws ParseException, IOException {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);

    FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
    FileBody filebodyBackground = new FileBody(new File(backgroundPath));

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("File", filebodyVideo);
    reqEntity.addPart("backgroundFile", filebodyBackground);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    Log.d("executing request ", httppost.getRequestLine().toString());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

    Log.d("Response - Status Line", response.getStatusLine().toString());
    if (resEntity != null) {
        Log.d("Entity Utils ", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }

    if (resEntity != null) {
        resEntity.consumeContent( );
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
}
```

Now how I can get data on my server and send back response to app that my server have this data?

Comment: What server are you using or planning to use?

Comment: I have VPS with Debian, there i have apache2 with php

Comment: Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: And there is any way to do auto-submit form?